# How to convert curly speech marks in string into straight speech marks

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, punctuation

I am reading in PDF files and converting each into a long string. The string has some words with speech marks that are curly like this:

`“Florals”`

I would like to convert these curly ones into straight speech marks:

`"Florals"`

Is there any way I can do this?

The reason is that giving me a unicode error when I convert my program into an executable - so would like to scan through the string and change it.

Comment: Does [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) not work? What error do you get? [Edit] your question to include a [mre] of your code and the full stack trace for the error. See [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.replace()` syntax is `string.replace('charcater you want to replace', 'character your using to replace')`

```
sentence = '“Florals”'

sentence = sentence.replace('“','"').replace('”','"')

print(sentence)
```

`.replace()` has been called twice because you want to replace two characters `“` and `”`.